# Python: Global variables in threads

Tags: python

I am trying to make my program work offline. The way i decided to to this is to have the main application work from memory in its own thread, whilst another thread read/writes data from the database.

I'm having issues with the variables being referenced before assignment.

```
import threading

class Data():
        global a
        global b
        a = 1
        b = 1



class A(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            a += 1


class B(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print a
            print b
            b -= 1


a_thr = A()
b_thr = B()
a_thr.start()
b_thr.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with threads. Setting

```
global variable
```

does not set this variable as global everywhere, but only in that function. Just add my changes to your code and it should run.

```
class A(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        global a
        global b
        while True:
            a += 1



class B(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        global a
        global b
        while True:
            print a
            print b
            b -= 1
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you